$\exp \left( \sum_{j \in J} A_j | j \rangle \langle j | \right) = ?$
I hope this is not an old question or duplicate. How does the following happen?
Let $\{| j \rangle\}_{j \in J}$ be an orthonormal basis and consider the operator $$A := \sum_{j \in J} A_j | j \rangle \langle j |$$ and take the exponential of it, i.e. $\exp(A)$.
Then on one hand
\begin{align}
\exp(A) = \exp \left( \sum_{j \in J} A_j | j \rangle \langle j | \right) 
= \prod_{j \in J} \exp( A_j | j \rangle \langle j | ) 
= \prod_{j \in J} \exp( A_j ) | j \rangle \langle j | 
= 0
\end{align}
where $$[| i \rangle \langle i |, | j \rangle \langle j |] = 0$$ implies $$\exp( A_i | i \rangle \langle i | + A_j | j \rangle \langle j | ) =  \exp( A_i | i \rangle \langle i | ) \exp( A_j | j \rangle \langle j | ).$$
On the other hand because
\begin{align}
\left( \sum_{j \in J} A_j | j \rangle \langle j | \right)^k 
&= \sum_{j_1 , ..., j_k \in J} A_{j_1} \cdots A_{j_k} | j_1 \rangle \langle j_1 | \cdots | j_k \rangle \langle j_k | \\
&= \sum_{j_1 , ..., j_k \in J} A_{j_1} \cdots A_{j_k} \delta_{j_1, j_2} \cdots \delta_{j_{k-1}, j_k} | j_1 \rangle \langle j_k | \\
&= \sum_{j \in J} A_j^k | j \rangle \langle j |
\end{align}
one has
\begin{align}
\exp(A) &= \exp \left( \sum_{j \in J} A_j | j \rangle \langle j | \right) \\
&= 1 
+ \left( \sum_{j \in J} A_j | j \rangle \langle j | \right)
+ \frac{1}{2!} \left( \sum_{j \in J} A_j | j \rangle \langle j | \right)^2
+ \frac{1}{3!} \left( \sum_{j \in J} A_j | j \rangle \langle j | \right)^3
+ \cdots \\
&= \sum_{j \in J} | j \rangle \langle j |
+ \sum_{j \in J} A_j | j \rangle \langle j |
+ \frac{1}{2!} \sum_{j \in J} A_j^2 | j \rangle \langle j |
+ \frac{1}{3!} \sum_{j \in J} A_j^3 | j \rangle \langle j |
+ \cdots \\
&= \sum_{j \in J} \left(1 
+  A_j 
+ \frac{1}{2!} A_j^2 
+ \frac{1}{3!} A_j^3 
+ \cdots \right) | j \rangle \langle j | \\
&= \sum_{j \in J} \exp(A_j) | j \rangle \langle j |
\end{align}
which clearly is not zero! So where is the mistake if there is any?

Hint:
$$ \exp \begin{pmatrix}a & 0  \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} =
\exp \begin{pmatrix}a & 0  \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  \exp \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0  \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}e^a & 0  \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & e^b \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} e^a & 0  \\ 0 & e^b \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Your first method is incorrect because it requires $\exp(0) = 0$, which is obviously false. In particular,
$$\exp(A_i \lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert) \neq \exp(A_i)\lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert.$$
You can see this by applying the definition of matrix exponential, using the characteristic property of a projector, and using a completeness relation
$$\begin{aligned} &\exp(A_i \lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert ) = \mathbb{I} + A_i\lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert + A_I^2 \lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert +... \\ &= \mathbb{I} - \lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert + \lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert + A_i\lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert + A_I^2 \lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert +... \\ &= \mathbb{I} -\lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert +\exp(A_i)\lvert i \rangle \langle i \lvert, \end{aligned}$$
which is much more obviously seen in a concrete matrix representation.
